# How to perform Secondary Sort in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, secondary-sort

I was searching for secondary sort using Spark and found this solution:

```
case class RFMCKey(cId: String, R: Double, F: Double, M: Double, C: Double)
class RFMCPartitioner(partitions: Int) extends Partitioner {
    require(partitions >= 0, "Number of partitions ($partitions) cannot be negative.")
    override def numPartitions: Int = partitions
    override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
    val k = key.asInstanceOf[RFMCKey]
    k.cId.hashCode() % numPartitions
    }
}
object RFMCKey {
    implicit def orderingBycId[A <: RFMCKey] : Ordering[A] = {
    Ordering.by(k => (k.R, k.F * -1, k.M * -1, k.C * -1))
    }
}
```

Now this is the code that I am using for my RFMC (Recency, Frequency, Monetary, Clumpiness) program.
In the same code, at the end, I am doing:

```
val rfmcTableSorted = rfmcTable.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new RFMCPartitioner(1))
```

But when I load this file in `spark-shell`, I get the following error:

```
<console>:130: error: RFMCKey is already defined as (compiler-generated) case class companion object RFMCKey
            object RFMCKey {
                       ^
<console>:198: error: RFMCKey.type does not take parameters
                                case (custId, (((rVal, fVal), mVal),cVal)) => (RFMCKey(custId, rVal, fVal, mVal, cVal), rVal+","+fVal+","+mVal+","+cVal)
                                                                                                              ^
<console>:200: error: value repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Nothing]
val rfmcTableSorted = rfmcTable.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new RFMCPartitioner(1)).cache()
```

How do I circumvent this issue?

**Update 1**

I tried changing the order of declaration of my case class and object class and surprisingly the shell loaded the file without throwing any errors. But when I ran my program it threw a new error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1623)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:286)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$rfmc$.constructRFMC(<console>:113)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
at $iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
at <init>(<console>:59)
at .<init>(<console>:63)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:856)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:813)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:656)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:669)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:996)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:944)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1058)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$rfmc$
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$rfmc$, value: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$rfmc$@757fc606)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$rfmc$$anonfun$17, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$rfmc$)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$rfmc$$anonfun$17, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
    ... 52 more
```

**Update 2**

The way I am defining my objects and functions is like this:

```
object rfmc {
  def constructrfmc() = {
    // Everything goes inside including the custom key and partitioner
    // code defined above
  }
}
```

**Update 3**

The way I am defining my code in eclipse which works perfectly is:

```
object rfmc extends App {
  // Everything goes inside including the custom key and partitioner
  // code defined above
}
```

I also created a JAR for this code and ran using `spark-submit` and that too worked perfectly.

Comment: Maybe your issue is linked to this : https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3772 . Maybe try to fiddle around with the order of declaration of your case class and your object.

Comment: I do not have time to answer, but have you had a look at this: http://codingjunkie.net/spark-secondary-sort/

Comment: @Vale I have actually done the same thing.

Comment: @Hawknight I tried swapping the order of declarations of case class and object and surprisingly it loaded the file properly. But when I ran my program it gave me `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` error which traced back to the object.

Comment: This means you've solved one part of the problem :) Do you have any object that isn't serializable that is being referenced in your Spark job ?

Comment: @Hawknight - No, there is none. I have just added the source code mentioned above. Actually I can successfully run this example in Eclipse IDE. I wanted to do the same in `spark-shell` but sadly I get the error mentioned in 'Update 1'.

Comment: @PunitNaik I believe there are some limitations in the shell that can't let you execute everything in Spark - are you using an accumulator by any chance ? Could you post exactly what you are typing in the shell to be able to help you further on this issue. You might also want to narrow down you search on the serialization problem by using the following parameter when running the `spark-shell` utility : `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true`

Comment: @Hawknight No, I am not using any accumulator. I cannot really post the entire  code as it is a proprietary code. On thing I can tell you is that the code runs fine if I do not include the 'Secondary Sort' part which of course includes defining custom keys and partitioner. Okay, I will try `spark-shell` with the option that you have suggested. But it is fine if the code does not work in `spark-shell` but works in an IDE or when deployed as a JAR, right?

Comment: @PunitNaik Either way, something is being used in your job that is not serializable and causes the `spark-shell` to throw the not serializable exception. One thing worth trying is to package your job as a jar (depending on your build tool, it can be sbt-assembly or maven-assembly-plugin), set up Spark in [standalone mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html), and run `spark-submit` with your jar. If this works, this means there are some limitations on Spark shell regarding custom keys and partitions. Keep me updated with how it goes for you.

Comment: @Hawknight Certainly I will!

Comment: @Hawknight - I changed my code sturcture as I have described in **Update 2**. I changed from `object rfmc` to `object rfmc extends App` and also I removed the `constructRFMC` function and just put everything inside the object. This was the way I was running it in my IDE. I created a JAR for the same and ran using `spark-submit` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @PunitNaik Great news, I'll go ahead and summarize in an answer what worked for you based on your input.

Comment: @Hawknight - Okay. You properly broke down your answer and it looks good to me. So I'll go on and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the issue that `RFMCKey` is already defined, you need to swap the order of your case class and object declaration as explained in [this issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3772).

Regarding your updates, there may be some limitations in the `spark-shell` that can't let execute any arbitrary code (such as with accumulators). To get more insight on the serialization mechanism, you should pass the following option `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true`. Remember that the spark-shell is more of an exploratory utility to test small portions of code or new features iteratively thanks to the REPL, and not a fully-fledged production-ready utility that should be used extensively to test your code.

Your safest option here is to package your app into a jar and set up Spark in [standalone mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html), and run `spark-submit` with your packaged jar. As reflected in update 3 and 4 of your post, you'll need to update your code to wrap it into an object so that it is the entry point of your job. This will enable you to make sure your code is not at fault here.